# Applying a loop to a list of lists in r

Tags: r, list, loops

I have the dataframe (Jdef), e.g.:

```
FocalID   Sex    Date    Time    Year_record Month_record Age Date_record
Adelaide   F 2014-06-22 07:41:04        2014            6 103      6 2014
Adelaide   F 2015-08-22 11:53:17        2015            8 117      8 2015
Adelaide   F 2014-06-16 12:30:18        2014            6 103      6 2014
Adelaide   F 2014-06-11 11:58:28        2014            6 103      6 2014
Adelaide   F 2014-07-05 14:10:23        2014            7 104      7 2014
Adelaide   F 2014-06-20 11:41:34        2014            6 103      6 2014
Adelaide   F 2014-06-04 09:39:34        2014            6 103      6 2014
Adelaide   F 2015-09-24 14:21:51        2015            9 119      9 2015
Adelaide   F 2015-08-15 13:09:07        2015            8 117      8 2015
Adelaide   F 2015-09-16 09:06:16        2015            9 118      9 2015
```

I've created a list of lists using:

```
Jdef$Date_record = paste(Jdef$Month_record, Jdef$Year_record)

listJ = split(Jdef, Jdef$Date_record)  
listJi = lapply(listJ, function(x) split(x, x$Age))
listJii = lapply(listJi, function(x) sapply(x, function(x) split(x, x$FocalID)))
```

Now I want to add, to each element of the listJii, all the records which were taken on the same month and year (same month and year as those of the records listed in each element of listJii) from Jdef. I've used the following:

```
data_to_add = list()
for(i in 1:length(listJii)){
data_to_add[[i]] <- unique(listJii[[i]]$Date_record)
}

listJ_subs = list()
for(i in 1:length(data_to_add)){
listJ_subs[[i]] <- subset(Jdef, Jdef$Date_record %in% data_to_add[[i]])
}
```

However, the loop won't work, saying that the index is out of range (data_to_add list results empty). I can't understand why. Does that have to do with the fact that listJii is a list of lists??

Comment: Please do use `dput()` to provide a reproducible and manageable example.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. I've edited the post adding a link to the original df extracted using dput(), as you suggested.

Comment: I can't see it. It's better if you post a small portion of the sample with `head( , n = 10)` or so.

Comment: `data_to_add` is empty because `listJii[[i]]$Date_record` does not exist. Your data frame is within three levels of list structures so you need to go deeper into the list structure. E.g., to get unique data records, you'll need more for loops to work with something like `listJii[[i]][[j]][[k]]$Data_record`

Comment: Yes, I had imagined that the problem was the multi-level structure of the list, but I can't figure out how to solve it...

Comment: @LC-datascientist I've tried this, but it won't work: `data_to_add = list()
for(i in seq_along(listJii)){
  for(j in seq_along(listJii[[i]])){
    for(k in seq_along(listJii[[j]])){
  data_to_add[[i]][[j]][[k]] <- unique(listJii[[i]][[j]][[k]]$Date_record)
  }}}`

Comment: @VittoriaRoatti what do you mean by add do u want a new data.frame that'll have all the records taken on the same day with the one of listJii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the `data_to_add` is empty. It is empty because `listJii[[i]]$Date_record` does not exist. Because a list of lists (i.e., a nested list) can be more confusing than a simple list or a data frame, you need to work through the layers of list structures (from *outside in*) to find the location of the vector that you seek. The `Date_record` in this case is in `listJii[[i]][[j]]`.

**How to build a nested loop to evaluate a vector in a nested list?**

A trick to getting the nested loops correct is to work from the *inside out*.

**Step 1.** Make sure the core function works, without using loops. 
Test the command line(s) with sample vectors in the nested list.

```r
unique(listJii[[1]][[1]]$Date_record) # this is what you want to store in `data_to_add`

# you have two layers of lists in `listJii`, so you need two list layers in `data_to_add`
data_to_add <- list()
data_to_add[[1]] <- list()
data_to_add[[1]][[1]] <- unique(listJii[[1]][[1]]$Date_record) 

# test
data_to_add # you needed all those commands above to make this work, so those will be necessary in your function
```

**Step 2.** Build your loops, one at a time, first by replacing the innermost variable  that needs changing and then work your way out. Test it every step along the way.

```r
## innermost loop test
data_to_add <- list()
data_to_add[[1]] <- list()
for(j in seq_along(listJii[[1]])) {
    data_to_add[[1]][[j]] <- unique(listJii[[1]][[j]]$Date_record)
}

# test
data_to_add # the innermost loop works


## outer loop test
data_to_add <- list()
for(i in seq_along(listJii)) {
    data_to_add[[i]] <- list()
    for(j in seq_along(listJii[[i]])) {
        data_to_add[[i]][[j]] <- unique(listJii[[i]][[j]]$Date_record)
    }
}

# test
data_to_add # the final loop works--this function is now ready
```

Your `listJsubs` function works with the `data_to_add` built here. Though, because nested lists are used in your evaluation, you may want to consider using nested loops to follow through for `listJsubs` as well.

**An alternative to using nested loops on nested lists is using nested `lapply()`**

`lapply()` is another function that you can use instead of for-loops over a list. 
Its output is a list, so you do not need to assign empty list structures beforehand to `data_to_add` and `data_to_add[[i]]` like the way you need for for-loops.

```r
data_to_add <- lapply(listJii, function(i){
    lapply(i, function(j){
        return(unique(j$Date_record))
    })
})
```

Note: the core function in this nested `lapply()` is a bit different from the one used in the nested for-loops. It's a different approach that I could do with `lapply()` and get the same results. I actually built it from *outside in*--hence, you don't see any `i` in the core function.

Comment: just as a note as OP already splits the data.frame on date we now for a fact that each split gonna have a single unique value i.e the value of the first row

Comment: Thank you @LC-datascientist! That's a really clear explanation! Do you think that it would be possible to maintain, in the new list 'listJ_subs' the same names of the elements as in the original 'listJii'? That is, the first element level would have the Date-record names, the second element level would have the Age numbers and the third element level would have the FocalID names.

Comment: @VittoriaRoatti replace `lapply` with `sapply`

Comment: @Abdessabour Mtk thank you! Maybe I am complicating my own life, but I was trying to do that with a for loop instead of lapply because that's the one that worked so far. However, maybe you have a different solution to 'add' data to the list (see my comments below).

Comment: In your for-loop for 'listJ_subs', you can replace `listJ_subs[[i]]` with `listJ_subs[[names(listJii)[i]]]`.

Comment: That is, with the change from `i` to `names(listJii)[i]`, you're calling the same names used in `listJii` outermost list, in the same order, to name the list elements in `listJ_subs`.

Answer (score 0):

Justa `tidyverse` solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)
Jdef %>% 
 nest_by(Date_record) %>%
  inner_join(Jdef %>% nest_by(Date_record, Age, FocalID, .key="Focalised")) -> nested
```

each row is equivalent to an element of the list.

```
# A tibble: 1,043 x 5
# Rowwise:  Date_record
   Date_record                 data   Age FocalID             Focalised
   <chr>       <list<tbl_df[,106]>> <dbl> <chr>    <list<tbl_df[,104]>>
 1 10 2018              [262 × 106]    26 Moussaka            [5 × 104]
 2 10 2018              [262 × 106]    27 Moussaka            [2 × 104]
 3 10 2018              [262 × 106]    33 Etosha              [2 × 104]
 4 10 2018              [262 × 106]    34 Etosha              [4 × 104]
 5 10 2018              [262 × 106]    35 Ishiguro            [1 × 104]
 6 10 2018              [262 × 106]    36 Houston             [1 × 104]
 7 10 2018              [262 × 106]    36 Ishiguro            [5 × 104]
 8 10 2018              [262 × 106]    36 Seuss               [1 × 104]
 9 10 2018              [262 × 106]    37 Houston             [4 × 104]
10 10 2018              [262 × 106]    37 Seuss               [5 × 104]
# … with 1,033 more rows
```

Using `tidyverse` loop through each row and append the

```r
nested %>%
   pmap(function(Date_record, data, Age, FocalID,  Focalised) 
        bind_rows(Focalised, data) %>% mutate(Date_record=Date_record) %>% replace_na(list(Age=Age,FocalID=FocalID))) -> res
res[[1]]
# A tibble: 262 x 107
   Sex   Date       Time  Year_record Month_record Troop ObsNumber ScanType Observer DOB_corrected MethDOB Year_birth Month_birth Age3mo Mother Parity NoInfants Absolute_rank
   <chr> <date>     <chr>       <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <date>        <chr>        <dbl>       <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>             <dbl>
 1 M     2018-10-24 11:4…        2018           10 J            15 10mScan  Charlot… 2016-07-26    BA            2016           7      9 Lusaka multi  5                     5
 2 M     2018-10-04 14:1…        2018           10 J            26 10mScan  Charlot… 2016-07-26    BA            2016           7      9 Lusaka multi  5                     5
 3 M     2018-10-23 10:3…        2018           10 J            16 10mScan  Charlot… 2016-07-26    BA            2016           7      9 Lusaka multi  5                     5
 4 M     2018-10-04 07:1…        2018           10 J             7 10mScan  Charlot… 2016-07-26    BA            2016           7      9 Lusaka multi  5                     5
 5 M     2018-10-14 08:1…        2018           10 J            13 10mScan  Charlot… 2016-07-26    BA            2016           7      9 Lusaka multi  5                     5
 6 M     2018-10-14 14:3…        2018           10 J            34 10mScan  Charlot… 2014-07-23    BE            2014           7     17 Preto… multi  4                    11
 7 M     2018-10-26 08:1…        2018           10 J            13 10mScan  Charlot… 2014-07-23    BE            2014           7     17 Preto… multi  4                    11
 8 M     2018-10-24 07:4…        2018           10 J             5 10mScan  Charlot… 2014-07-23    BE            2014           7     17 Preto… multi  4                    11
 9 M     2018-10-23 07:1…        2018           10 J             3 10mScan  Charlot… 2014-07-23    BE            2014           7     17 Preto… multi  4                    11
10 M     2018-10-30 08:2…        2018           10 J            21 10mScan  Charlot… 2014-07-23    BE            2014           7     17 Preto… multi  4                    11
```

Also if you want to just get the dates `split` already puts thos in the names of the elements so :

```r
rep(names(listJii), lengths(listJii))
```

`purrr`:

```r
listJii %>% map(map,  map, `[[`, 1, "Date_record")
```

`baseR`:

```r
lapply(listJii, lapply, lapply, `[`, 1, "Date_record")
```

Some splits are not `data.frames` which may throw some errors, and is the reason why the `rep` solution isn't equivalent to `purrr|baseR`

Comment: @VittoriaRoatti you didn't mention how you want to "add" the records

Comment: Yes sorry, maybe it wasn't clear. After creating listJii and data_to_add, I wanted to add, to each FocalID sub-element of listJii, all the records taken on the same month and year. I need that because I will then apply a social network function and, to analyze social networks change through time, I will need to have a list of lists in which each FocalID has its own network at each Age and Date_record period. So, I thought to add data by doing a loop and using data_to_add to create listJ_subs, in which all records from Jdef that were taken on the same month/year as in data_to_add are included.

Comment: Also, your tidyverse solution looks great (and straightforward), but the output is different from that of my original listJii (created with lapply), so I am not sure if it's just a different way of visualizing the list or if the list structure is different...(sorry, I am new to lists..). Actually I should note that 'add' is a confusing term used in this case because I am not adding, but rather filling an element of the new listJ_subs with data...

Comment: @VittoriaRoatti do you need to exclude the records that have the same `FocalID`?

Comment: @VittoriaRoatti I think what you're trying to do is redundant and that's because of the fact that the last code is basically just copying the the data created in that `date_record`; also each row of the column focalised is equivalent to an element in the nested list.

Comment: No, I don't need to exclude the rows with the same FocalID.

Comment: @VittoriaRoatti check the edit, however as I mentioned earlier it's redundant.